Python: Alias a module (in other libraries)
Suppose I have two python installs. Let's say my global python3.7, and a python3.10 venv.
Between 3.7 and 3.10, a module changed its name from foo to foobar. So in 3.7, we would do import foo, and in python 3.10, we'd do import foobar.
Suppose my code is structured like:
py3.7_project/src
py3.10_project/src
common/src

Code in common/src must be able to import foo, whether it is running in 3.7 or 3.10.
However, other dependencies in site-packages will import it by the name expected by that version, so it's not as simple as renaming virtualenv-3.10/site-packages/foobar to site-packages/foo.
Fixing any individual file is simple:
try:
    import foo
except ImportError:
    import foobar as foo

And we can potentially put this in a shim, foo_resolver.py that creates the correct exports. However, that still requires updating all imports to foo_resolver, communicating to all stakeholders that all imports should use foo_resolver from now on, etc.
Is there a way to make import foo import foobar/__init__.py in the python3.10 context, ideally without changing all my imports to import foo_resolver as foo or messing with links in site-packages?

(I suppose one solution is to name my shim foo.py. That feels like bad practice to me, but maybe the situation calls for it?)

I never tried this but you could play around with sys.modules e. g. by importing foo_resolver very early in your code and moving it to the 'foo' key of sys.modules. Further import foo will then use the cached module.

The sys.modules manipulation thing leads to "evil twin" modules.

"Between 3.7 and 3.10, a module changed its name from foo to foobar" - what module are you dealing with? I can't think of any stdlib modules that changed name during the Python 3.x series, and third-party module names aren't bound to the Python release cycle. The closest thing I can think of is stuff like the collection ABCs getting moved out of collections and into collections.abc, but you should access those through collections.abc on both Python 3.7 and 3.10.

@user2357112 There shouldn't be an evil twin because I wrote to move the imported shim module foo_resolver to the 'foo' key. So we end up with the shim under the 'foo' key only and the foobar module under its own key only.
